# How to make Unrecognized character escape '.' (code 46) to be Recognized - com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException

Tags: java, json, xml, elasticsearch, jackson

I see this issue in docker-compose logs from magento2 container. Yeah, looking for the issue in some Magento2 plugin is nice idea and way to go, but for now it is not clear what is the reason of issue. There is an assumption that the problem comes from this string "**Pris per fp. .**" and few similar strings in product description.

It would be great if some ElasticSearch setting or even some patching could teach Jackson to ignore "." sequence for now, while it is not clear how to force Magento2 to reproduce the issue.

Currently I can reproduce the issue without Magento2 installed and hope to find a place where someone describes the way to work it out.

```
# Start an elasticsearch instance
docker run \
    --env 'node.name=mage-single-node' \
    --env 'cluster.name=mage-single-node' \
    --env 'discovery.type=single-node' \
-d --name=demo-es -p9200:9200 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.17;

curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_search?" \
-H"Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\."
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: It would be great if I had a million bucks. But just like I'm not gonna get it, neither are you gonna find a JSON parser that accepts bad data. Fix your data.

Answer (score 3):

JSON only allows certain characters to be preceded by a `\`, and `.` isn't one of them. You can't change the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/), and you're not going to persuade the authors of your JSON parser to accept invalid input, so you have to change your data to conform with the spec. That's what standards are for.